# '/snap/bin' is not included in Ubuntu 18.0.4

Tags: docker, microk8s

While installing `MicroK8s` on a single node, getting below error while getting status of `microk8s` :

```
The command could not be located because '/snap/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
microk8s.status: command not found
```

I have done export `PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin`

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

Still getting same error. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can try this to install snap on ubuntu 18

> https://codeburst.io/how-to-install-and-use-snap-on-ubuntu-18-04-9fcb6e3b34f9